# Save variable in while loop (dice game)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

player1=1

def dice_roll_1():
    while player1 <49:

            r=input("Press r to roll ")

            roll_1 = random.randint(1,6)
            roll_2 = random.randint(1,6)
            print(roll_1)
            print(roll_2)
            total=(roll_1 + roll_2)
            print("Total dice roll",total)
            print(total+player1)

dice_roll_1()
```

I'm working on this for school and I am so stuck. When it loops it resets the player1 variable back to 1.
I need it to keep the total throughout the loop.
For example, if they rolled a 12, it would add to player1 and player 1 would equal 13.
Then on the next turn if they rolled a 6 it would add to that 13 to become 19.

Comment: You're never changing `player1`.  You need to do `player1 = ...` at some point in your loop

Answer (score 2):

Update the value. Then print it

```
print("Total dice roll",total)
player1 += total
print(player1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never change the value of player1.

It is assigned only once...

This is the reason that the value is always "1"

Check the code below, and use the line:
player1 += total

I've also added a check to see what they've input in case it is not "r"

```
import random

player1=1

def dice_roll_1():
    while player1 <49:

        r=input("Press r to roll ")
        # if something else was entered, then continue on to the next roll
        if r != 'r':
            continue

        roll_1 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print(roll_1)
        print(roll_2)
        total=(roll_1 + roll_2)
        print("Total dice roll",total)
        # need to update the player's total
        player1 += total
        print(player1)

dice_roll_1()

print("Final total for player 1: " + player1)
```